# Delete duplicate row in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

This is a tricky one:

How can I delete 1 instance of a duplicate row from a table with only 1 column.

Eg.. Input Table: temp

```
myColumn
   1
   2
   2
   3
   4
```

I want to delete one instance of 2 without using a temporary table.

Output Table:

```
myColumn
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

NOTE: You cannot use temporary table and SQL should be written in Teradata syntax only.

Comment: If you can't use a temporary table it's impossible (unless the ROWID is enabled on your system, which is very unlikely).

Comment: @Andrew: How to populate with a ROW_NUMBER? :-)

Comment: ah, see, I shouldn't be offering suggestions before I've had my tea...

Comment: Add a column, populate it with row_number() partition by myColumn order by myColumn and delete all rownums>1